# Power Supply / Motherboard fake death after power outage?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

Every time I lose power - or just disconnect power from my PC for some time - it will be dead. The USB ports / audio ports will get power (I can hear my speakers pop when I turn the PSU on) but when I press the power button, nothing happens. No LEDs, no fans, literally dead silence. Nothing even moves.

The only way I can get it to run again is - and I know this sounds like a nightmare, because it is - is to unplug the 24-pin molex connector and insert it, with power on it, tilted until the mobo starts freaking out. After that, push it in all the way, start the PC, everything runs fine & stable with no issue whatsoever, even under full load, so I doubt any of the components are actually broken.

Any idea what is going on there? Is there a safety thing that triggered and just thinks it knows better when to turn off than I do? Any better way than this scary BS that would fix the issue? I tried unplugging and pressing the power button for a minute, nothing. Pressed Reset button, nothing.

Setup:

`2x EVGA Kingpin 780 GTX Ti
EVGA SuperNova 1300 PSU
AsRock Z97 Extreme4 mobo`

P.S.: I looked at all the "your PSU is busted", "is the power working?", "your mobo is broken" answers which are obviously wrong for my use case. The system is fine and running 100% test loads on GPU, MEM and CPU and gaming on highest settings for hours fine once I did this one-time hack. Once I do it, and it keeps powered, there are no issues, ever. Shutting down and booting works as expected - until the next power outage.

Comment: Have you tried simply disconnecting the power supply for an hour before turning it back on again.  It almost sounds to me like some over-active (stuffed) protection circuitry in the PSU.  Replacing the PSU sounds like the easiest way to solve it.

Comment: I let it stand without power the last time over night, nothing happened either. I guess I can reach out to EVGA if they would exchange the PSU for that. But why would it also happen when I normally shut down the PC, turn off the PSU and the unplug it. If I leave it disconnected for more than a minute or so, same issue.